# Query multiple elements without specifying the element name

Tags: xpath, xquery

This may be a silly question, but is it possible to make a query using XPath without specifying the element name?
Normally I would write something like

```
//ElementName[@id = "some_id"]
```

But the thing is I have many (about 40) different element types with an `id` attribute and I want to be able to return any of them if the id fits. But I don't want to make this call for each type individually. Is it possible to search all of them at once, regardless of the name?

I am using this in an XQuery script, if that offers any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use * instead of name `//*[@id = "some_id"]`

Answer (score 1):

It might be more efficient to look directly at the @id elements - //* will work, but will initially return every node in the document and then filter!

That may not matter in a small document, of course.  but here's an alternative:

```
//@id[.="some_id"]/..
```

Comment: Actually it does matter very much since I am quering from a database with many (over 100.000 elements).

Comment: If it's an XML database such as MarkLogic or eXist, you may find that certain attributes (like @id) are indexed, which may also favour this alternative.

Comment: Actually, I am using eXist and I have asked in the eXist mailing list what was most efficient. Here is what Wolfgang Meier (original creator of eXist) replied:
_eXist optimizes the wildcard step in //*[@id = "some_id"] and
basically does the same as `//@id[.="some_id"]/..`. eXist will first evaluate `@id = "some_id"`, then compute which parent elements of `@id` would match the wildcard._
But for general XPath queries I believe your suggestion is valid.